# How to unit test Pydantic validators?

Tags: python, pydantic

I have a Pydantic class that performs custom validation

```
class MyClass(BaseModel):
    foo: str

    @validator('foo')
    def perform_custom_validation(cls, val):
       # we would normally perform custom validation logic here on the value val
       raise ValueError('Always fails')
```

I want to test my validation logic:

```
def create_class(a_foo: str):
   MyClass(foo=a_foo)


# now inside my unit test
with self.assertRaises(ValidationError):
   create_class('fail')
```

I think I should be catching that exception, but my unit test does not see the exception and so my unit test fails. However, if I run `create_class` outside of that context manager then the exception occurs and my code fails.

How am I supposed to test that this exception is thrown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could easily have given a working example. If you had done so, you would probably have noticed that the unit tests pass, as expected.

**so.py**

```py
from unittest import TestCase, main
from pydantic import BaseModel, validator, ValidationError

class MyClass(BaseModel):
    foo: str

    @validator('foo')
    def perform_custom_validation(cls, val):
       # we would normally perform custom validation logic here on the value val
       raise ValueError('Always fails')

def create_class(a_foo: str):
   MyClass(foo=a_foo)

class Tests(TestCase):
    def test_validation(self):

        # now inside my unit test
        with self.assertRaises(ValidationError):
           create_class('fail')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

```bash
$ python so.py
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK
```

If *your* unit test is failing, please provide the code for it so we can reproduce.

Comment: You're quite right, it was a different error in some closed-source code I wasn't in a position to share. Thanks for this, the second pair of eyes helped!